# In the code "{ exec >/dev/null; } >/dev/null" what is happening under the hood?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, io-redirection, file-descriptors

When you redirect a command list that contains an exec redirection, the exec >/dev/null doesn't seem to still be applied afterwards, such as with:

```
{ exec >/dev/null; } >/dev/null; echo "Hi"
```

"Hi" is printed.

I was under the impression that `{}` command list is not considered a subshell unless it is part of a pipeline, so the `exec >/dev/null` should still be applied within the current shell environment in my mind.

Now if you change it to:

```
{ exec >/dev/null; } 2>/dev/null; echo "Hi"
```

there is no output as expected; file descriptor 1 remains pointed at /dev/null for future commands as well. This is shown by rerunning:

```
{ exec >/dev/null; } >/dev/null; echo "Hi"
```

which will give no output.

I tried making a script and stracing it, but I am still unsure exactly what is happening here.

At each point in this script what is happening to the STDOUT file descriptor?

EDIT:
Adding my strace output:

```
read(255, "#!/usr/bin/env bash\n{ exec 1>/de"..., 65) = 65
open("/dev/null", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
fcntl(1, F_GETFD)                       = 0
fcntl(1, F_DUPFD, 10)                   = 10
fcntl(1, F_GETFD)                       = 0
fcntl(10, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)          = 0
dup2(3, 1)                              = 1
close(3)                                = 0
close(10)                               = 0
open("/dev/null", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
fcntl(1, F_GETFD)                       = 0
fcntl(1, F_DUPFD, 10)                   = 10
fcntl(1, F_GETFD)                       = 0
fcntl(10, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)          = 0
dup2(3, 1)                              = 1
close(3)                                = 0
dup2(10, 1)                             = 1
fcntl(10, F_GETFD)                      = 0x1 (flags FD_CLOEXEC)
close(10)                               = 0
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0666, st_rdev=makedev(1, 3), ...}) = 0
ioctl(1, TCGETS, 0x7ffee027ef90)        = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
write(1, "hi\n", 3)                     = 3
```

Comment: That's strange; I can't reproduce the `close(10)`. Can you also post your entire script contents that you ran strace on?

Comment: @DepressedDaniel Here is the full script and strace: [script](https://ptpb.pw/~redirexec/bash) [strace](https://ptpb.pw/~execstrace/)

Comment: You have a stray `;` after `}`, which changes the meaning of `> /dev/null` to not apply to the compound list `{}` after all.

Comment: @DepressedDaniel Ah, you are completely correct! Now the output is what I expect; thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Let's follow

```
{ exec >/dev/null; } >/dev/null; echo "Hi"
```

step by step.

1. There are two commands:

   a. `{ exec >/dev/null; } >/dev/null`, followed by

   b. `echo "Hi"`

   The shell executes first the command (a) and then the command (b).
2. The execution of `{ exec >/dev/null; } >/dev/null` proceeds as follows:

   a. First, the shell perform the redirection `>/dev/null` *and remembers to undo it when the command ends*.

   b. Then, the shell executes `{ exec >/dev/null; }`.

   c. Finally, the shell switches standard output back to where is was. (This is the same mechanism as in `ls -lR /usr/share/fonts >~/FontList.txt` -- redirections are made only for the duration of the command to which they belong.)
3. Once the first command is done the shell executes `echo "Hi"`. Standard output is wherever it was before the first command.

Comment: Is there some reason behind why 2a is executed before 2b? (right-to-left)

Comment: Redirections _must_ be executed before the command to which they apply, no? How could they work otherwise?

Comment: Aha,  never thought of it that way!  First two are borh great answers; giving it a little bit before I decide on one, but I appreciate both explanations!

Comment: Unfortunately I can only pick one answer, so I am going with this one since it is a bit less technical and thus I think it would be able to help even the less tech-savvy users. However @DepressedDaniel had an equally great answer [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/331764/in-the-code-exec-dev-null-dev-null-what-is-happening-under-the-hood/331768#331768) that offers a more in depth explanation.

Answer (score 14):

In order to not use a sub-shell or sub-process, when the output of a compound list `{}` is piped `>`, the shell saves the STDOUT descriptor before running the compound list and restores it after. Thus the `exec >` in the compound list does not carry its effect past the point where the old descriptor is reinstated as STDOUT.

Let's take a look at the relevant part of `strace bash -c '{ exec >/dev/null; } >/dev/null; echo hi' 2>&1 | cat -n`:

```
   132  open("/dev/null", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
   133  fcntl(1, F_GETFD)                       = 0
   134  fcntl(1, F_DUPFD, 10)                   = 10
   135  fcntl(1, F_GETFD)                       = 0
   136  fcntl(10, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)          = 0
   137  dup2(3, 1)                              = 1
   138  close(3)                                = 0
   139  open("/dev/null", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
   140  fcntl(1, F_GETFD)                       = 0
   141  fcntl(1, F_DUPFD, 10)                   = 11
   142  fcntl(1, F_GETFD)                       = 0
   143  fcntl(11, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)          = 0
   144  dup2(3, 1)                              = 1
   145  close(3)                                = 0
   146  close(11)                               = 0
   147  dup2(10, 1)                             = 1
   148  fcntl(10, F_GETFD)                      = 0x1 (flags FD_CLOEXEC)
   149  close(10)                               = 0
```

You can see how, on line 134, descriptor `1` (`STDOUT`) is copied onto another descriptor with index at least `10` (that's what `F_DUPFD` does; it returns the lowest available descriptor starting at the given number after duplicating onto that descriptor). Also see how, on line 137, the result of `open("/dev/null")` (descriptor `3`) is copied onto descriptor `1` (`STDOUT`). Finally, on line `147`, the old `STDOUT` saved on descriptor `10` is copied back onto descriptor `1` (`STDOUT`). The net effect is to insulate the change to `STDOUT` on line `144` (which corresponds to the inner `exec >/dev/null`).

Comment: Since FD 1 is overwritten by FD 3 on line 137, why does line 141 not point 10 to /dev/null?

Comment: @JoeyPabalinas Line 141 is duplicating FD 1 (i.e., stdout) to *the next available descriptor after 10*, which turns out to be 11, as you can see in the return value from that system call. 10 is just hard-coded into bash so that bash's descriptor saving won't interfere with single-digit descriptors you might manipulate in your script via `exec`.

Comment: So then fcntl(1, F_DUPFD, 10) will always refer to STDOUT no matter where FD 1 is currently pointing?

Comment: @JoeyPabalinas Not sure what your question is. FD 1 **IS** STDOUT. They are the same thing.

Comment: Added full strace output to my original post.

Comment: Your strace output actually differs from mine (missing the first close(10)).

Answer (score 9):

The difference between `{ exec >/dev/null; } >/dev/null; echo "Hi"` and `{ exec >/dev/null; }; echo "Hi"` is that the double redirection does `dup2(10, 1);` before closing fd 10 which is the copy of the original `stdout`, before running the next command (`echo`).

It happens that way because the outer redirect is actually overlaying the inner redirect.  That's why it copies back the original `stdout` fd once it completes.

Comment: +1 for explaining the difference in easy way. AlexP's answer lacks of this explanation.

Comment: Short, but to the point. +1